# (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError) in db:migrate, only on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a ruby/rails program. I'm trying to do a `rake db:migrate`, when I'm on my own machine, it works fine. When I'm using my heroku instance, and run:  `heroku run rake db:migrate --app APPNAME`  it gives:

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:231:in `search_for': Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'fileutils (= 1.0.2)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
```

I've made sure that fileutils is in my Gemfile, and I've manually run: `heroku run gem install fileutils -v 1.0.2  --app APPNAME` but that doesn't seem to help any.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why the use of gem install ? Are you using bundler/Gemfile for your rails project ? The dependencies should be precisely specced in `Gemfile.lock` and follow through using `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!